# Equivalent tag to 'homework': 'do-my-job-for-me'?

Tags: discussion, tags

In the same way that questions which are obviously homework get tagged [homework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/homework), should questions which are obviously attempts to get someone else to do the questioner's job for them be tagged [do-my-job-for-me](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/do-my-job-for-me)?

I'm not even sure whether I'm joking or not... with a decent tag wiki entry it might even become a useful user education tool.

Comment: I think liberal application of `-1` on these sorts of questions should work *nearly* as well.  Down votes on questions are "free" (as in reputation-flavored-beer) so there is no loss incurred.

Comment: Oh man, I've only just gotten out of my "stupid question, downvote" reflex, since I thought it was costing me rep.  If it isn't, on the other hand...

Comment: @womble downvotes on questions are free, answers still cost you 1 rep however.

Comment: What's a few rep on downvotes to the #7 overall ranking user anyway :P

Comment: @womble [Yup, they're free now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

Comment: @Ben: I have a, shall we say, *significant* downvote rate from my last stint here.  I'm much less critical of rampant stupidity these days, though.

Comment: Maybe I'm just odd but if I feel a question or answer deserves a downvote I give it one and really couldn't care less if it costs me one miserable point of rep. Seriously, is there any regular that can't afford to lose a point or two from time to time?

Comment: WE NEEDS IT ALL, MY PRECIOUS!

Answer (score 6):

I say no. Tags are a means of categorising questions, and in my opinion this isn't helping anybody find the questions they're looking for.

**Edit**: I'd actually go as far to say that [homework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/homework) and [do-my-job-for-me](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/do-my-job-for-me) are probably both meta tags and shouldn't be used as per [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: This tag would categorise questions that people might not want to answer because they're huge, ill-defined, etc etc, which then helps them find the questions they want to answer quicker.  Is the 'homework' tag a means of categorising questions that helps people find the questions they're looking for?

Comment: Obvious homework questions usually get closed as off topic quite quickly, I'm surprised that the [tag:homework] tag still exists.

Comment: @Iain I don't suspect it will for long. :) womble appears to be actively working to change that.

Comment: Indeed I am.  All done now.