# Death to the homework tag!

Tags: support, tags

On the basis of the answer my [previous question](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1785/equivalent-tag-to-homework-do-my-job-for-me) (and the SO blog post linked to therein), I've bulldozed all homework tags from questions on serverfault.  Anyone with the appropriate mod bits want to handle the behind-the-scenes stuff required to make the tag go away completely and forever?

Comment: Only SE employees can blacklist tags. If you don't hear from them from this question, pop them an email at team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm all for the death of the [tag:homework] tag since downvotes on questions are now free, and for all the reasons previously mentioned on the linked question.

Comment: As an added bonus: questions with vote-totals of less than zero *are automatically deleted* after a certain period of time.

Comment: Got a cite for that, @sysadmin1138?  I'm fairly sure I've found ancient questions with negative vote-totals in my travels through the dark underground of SF.

Comment: @Womble Try this: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1210/cleaning-house-really-old-unloved-questions/1214#1214

Comment: Hot diggety I like the look of that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the [homework](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/homework) has zero questions now. If it keeps coming back and you can't keep up with it without blacklisting, feel free to make another meta post. Thanks!