# Death to [newbie]!

Tags: support, tags

Not to newbies themselves, of course...

As part of the continuing [war on metatags](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1787/death-to-the-homework-tag), I've cleaned up all 36 or so questions that were tagged 'newbie', and would appreciate an SE employee blacklisting the tag for the future.

Comment: Quick note, if you're going to retag more than say, 15-20, leave a note on meta so that one of us can retag where nessesary, because we don't raelly want the front page flooded with retags. When we had to retag `vmware` it took us about a week, but it meant that questions weren't getting pushed off the front page.

Comment: Moderator retags don't trip the 'updated' logic?  I don't mind leaving it to mods (less work for me), but do you guys really want to have to do all of that?

Comment: If we do a normal update, it still trips it, but we also have other tools such as mass merges that we can do that don't trip it.

Comment: You mods and your super-cow powers...

Comment: It's not all mod-hammer flailing around here. It takes a deft hand to knock those tags just right so everything falls into place.

Comment: Also, if we have to do a mass retag for whatever reason, best to do them on the weekend and in small groups, when the site is pretty slow anyway and to push less questions off.

Answer (score 1):

Really. When doing these large merges, announce them here *first*. We've taken to doing mass retags in dribs and drabs instead of the rip-the-bandaid-off-oh-%(#**%)(!-that-hurt method. If anything, it'll get a few more names in the big stream and it'll look less concerning to see an entire front page with a single name.

Comment: But how else can I become famous?  Supermodels won't return my calls, and I don't have enough core strength to plank on a world-famous monument.